# SYN receives RST,ACK very frequently

Tags: sql-server, linux, sockets, proxy, network-programming

Hi Socket Programming experts,

I am writing a proxy server on Linux for SQL server 2005/2008 running on Windows. 
The proxy is coded using bsd sockets and in C, and it is working fine with a problem described below.

When I use a database client (written in JAVA, and running on a Linux box) to fire queries (with a concurrency of 100 or more) directly to the Database server, not experiencing connection resets. But through my proxy I am experiencing many connection resets.

Digging deeper I came to know that connection from 'DB client' to 'Proxy' always succeeds
but when the 'Proxy' tries to connect to the DB server the connection fails, due to the SYN packet getting RST,ACK.

That was to give some background. The question is :
Why does sometimes SYN receives RST,ACK?

```
DB client(linux) to Server(windows)  ----> Works fine
DB client(linux) to Proxy(Linux) to Server(windows) -----> problematic
```

I am aware that this can happen in "connection refused" case but this definitely is not that one. SYN flooding might be another scenario, but that does not explain fine behavior while firing to Server directly.

I am suspecting some socket option setting may be required, that the client does before connecting and my proxy does not. Please put some light on this. Any help (links or pointers) is most appreciated.

Additional info:

Wrote a C client that does concurrent connections, which takes concurrency as an argument. Here are my observations: 
  -> At 5000 concurrency and above, some connects failed with 'connection refused'.
  -> Below 2000, it works fine.

But the actual problem is observed even at a concurrency of 100 or more. 
Note: The problem is time dependent sometimes it never comes at all and sometimes it is very frequent and DB client (directly to server) works fine at all times .

Comment: I'm assuming when you were talking about "SQL Database running on Windows" you were talking about SQL Server.  Please change the tag if necessary, but please note: this is important info missing.

Comment: Thanks JayC, I thought it was not relevant to the problem at hand. Editing it.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server needs [worker threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187024.aspx) to accept incoming connections. If your server is worker starved (which can be easily diagnosed by a high number of entries in [`sys.dm_os_tasks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174963.aspx) in `PENDING` state) then attempting to open new connection will fail. So likely what I suspect it happens is that you're pushing to the server more workload that it can handle. You need to optimize the workload or get a beefier server.

Clients like Java client make effective use of [connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) and, even under a high load, do not need to open new connection hence you do not see this problem, instead you see only delays in requests completion.

Comment: Hi Remus, Thanks for responding. I have not enabled connection pooling in JAVA client. And even if it is enabled, when pooling is used connections are not closed, and since I am using the same client the problem would not be seen through proxy too. It is while opening new connection the problem is seen.  Checked sys.dm_os_tasks and found that at a concurrency of 400, 68 connection are in PENDING state.

Comment: How long do they stay in `PENDING` state? use [`sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks.wait_duration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188743.aspx). How does this compare to when you use the Java client?

Comment: They stay in pending states for a very short period of time. When I check again they vanish away. Even when I point the JAVA client directly(to server) some connections are in PENDING states at the server side for short duration. I think this may not be capturing the resetted connections since it is handled by TCP layer itself without the application becoming aware of their presence. I dont know if sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks queries the OS for such info. Using wireshark I can clearly see RST,ACK being returned from server for the SYN from proxy.

Answer (score 0):

A listening socket keeps queue of established connections and connections in establishment process (e.g. SYN got, SYNACK replied, but not ACK from client yet). If a established queue overflows, IP stack reaction differs on OS. The most traditional approach was to ignore newcoming SYNs, waiting when userland accept()s and frees a slot in the queue. With SYN flooding attacks in mid-90s, the new method was invented named "SYN cookies" which drops need for establishment queue totally, in cost of need to support special TCP option.
OTOH I have heard that Windows stacks change their behavior - under some conditions, the reaction to queue overflow is RST response. In earlier stacks (e.g. Win95) this was the main response and client side was correspondingly changed to ignore RST response to SYN:(
That's why I guess that some proxy host feature triggers RST in Windows stack.

Another guess is that DB server closes listening socket at all under some condition (e.g. detected overload peak) which appears only with proxy.

Comment: Hi Netch, Thanks for your response, Do you mean I will have to make my proxy to ignore this particular case and retry connecting for sometime before actually failing..... In your last statement, you said "which appears only with proxy". Can DB server know it is talking to a proxy or an actual client??

Answer (score 0):

When the SYN receives the RST response, it should not be the problem of SQL-SERVER.

Because the application is able to `accept` the socket only after the tcp handshake finished.

Is there any device between the Proxy and the SQL-Server machines?

Try to make sure that the RST response come from sql-server machine.

You connection count is far from SYN-FLOOD, I think.

Comment: Hi llj098, that is a good point. Will verify if RST comes only between the proxy m/c and the server m/c. Can also check this by running the JAVA client from the proxy m/c when the problem comes again. Will update you.